# Network outage when PC goes to sleep or shuts down

Tags: networking, ethernet, hardware-failure

About once every 100 times when my PC goes to sleep, the entire network stops working. I have two switches, and everything goes down, not just the switch that has the PC plugged in. For instance, in the diagram below, the Raspberry Pi cannot communicate with the server, even though it's not connected to the same switch as the PC. In the drawing, the double lines indicate 10GbE (over Cat6 cable) and the single lines are 1GbE or 2.5GbE. (Many irrelevant devices are omitted). The laptop is temporarily connected with one of the red arrows.

[image: Network diagram]

The gaming PC has dual boot, and this problem happens in Windows and Linux modes. I have tried to disable Flow Control on the PC and the server, but I'm not sure if I've got it persistently disabled.

When probing the network with Wireshark on either of the switches in this fault state, there is no traffic whatsoever (or just outbound traffic). It's not possible to reach hosts that are connected to the same switch. The LEDs are blinking on the switches 10G ports.

My suspects are the TP-Link TX401 network card or the QSW-2104-2T switches, or configuration error, but I don't feel comfortable sending a warranty claim when I don't know what's wrong.

---

Troubleshooting / Recovery:

- When the PC is powered back on (or resumed), the network always recovers after a few seconds.
- Unplug the PC: Does not solve the problem.
- Disconnect cable betwen the switches: communication between devices on switch 1 is restored after about 10 seconds.

- [The following is after BOTH the PC is unplugged and then the switches disconnected: After connecting the switches again, switch 1 keeps working, but the devices on switch 2 are still unable to communicate. Power cycle switch 2 fixes it.]
- Swap the two switches - didn't help.
- Swap the PC and uplink ports on Switch2: No - it seems to be irrelevant which one is in port 1 and port 2 (but it took a very long time for the problem to manifest again).
- When the PC is in sleep mode, unplug the PC and then later re-plug it. The problem persists whilst the PC is unplugged, but the network recovers when it's plugged in again (still in sleep mode).
- Remove the uplink between the switches, and instead connect the switches to two bridged ports on the server. Results pending. (This is a sub-optimal config for me, but useful for troubleshooting)

Comment: Did you try when this happens to physically disconnect the PC from the network to see if this restores connectivity? You may also try to turn off its QNAP (switch 2).

Comment: Does any of the devices have a static ip, and is the DHCP server properly configured to not deal any IP address in this scope? It almost sounds like when your pc connects again, its been given an IP address that conflicts with one of the devices. Maybe one of the routers/switches.

Comment: harrymc I disconnected the PC and I believe it recovered, but I will try these things next time & update the question.  LFChip I believe I would see some traffic in Wireshark if that was the case. Most things use DHCP, from a VM with pfSense on the server. Certain Arduino devices have hard-coded IP addresses, as does some home automation containers on the server, and all of these lose connection as well. Thanks both for the replies!

Comment: After I wrote this question, it hasn't happened until now ,so I thougth it was fixed. It seems much less frequent that 1 in 20 times, at least. I will keep trying different things when it happens, and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a "**bypass mode**" in your gaming PC's network interface card. When your computer shuts down or goes to sleep, bypass mode is enabled, and then two network links are connected at the layer 2 (the data link layer). image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9uF9.png

You should enable **Spanning Tree Protocol** (STP) to ensure that you do not create loops when you have redundant paths in your network. [Enable the Spanning Tree Protocol](https://docs.qnap.com/operating-system/qts/4.3.x/en-us/GUID-BBD9A1AF-4552-4DEA-B320-1FD529EB772D.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this was just a bad network diagram. There's just one connection to the switch, but I had drawn 10Gb links as double lines. Fixed now.